# How to solve Android Oreo Socket connection issue

Tags: java, android, sockets, android-wifi, android-8.0-oreo

I'm getting this error when trying to create a Socket(IP, PORT) via Wifi Hotspot.
failed to connect to /192.168.43.1 (port 9802) from /:: (port 33044): connect failed: ECONNABORTED (Software caused connection abort). 
How to solve this issue?

```
public void run() {

    mRun = true;

    try {


        Log.d("TCP Client", "C: Connecting...");
        //create a socket to make the connection with the server
        socket = new Socket(SERVER_IP, SERVER_PORT);

        try {

            //sends the message to the server
            mBufferOut = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);

            //receives the message which the server sends back
            mBufferIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
```

Thanks in advance.
:)

Comment: And ... Any questions? And please only express thank after being helped. That is the protocol.